# How can I launch a JavaScript or jQuery event when I reach the top of my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple problem, but I can't find the solution ...
I just want to launch an event (which execute a method) when I scroll my page up and I "touch" the top of it. I'm using JavaScript and jQuery in my page. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Should it also be launched when you open the page (because you're always on top when you open a website)?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: `body.on.scroll = function() { if (window.is.top || document.above.fold && google.search.is.not.done() || I put(no.effort.into.this) ) alert('I'll do more research!'); }`

Comment: @adeneo The string you're passing to alert contains an unterminated string literal! :D

Comment: @adeneo : I know that I can easily find a solution online ;-), but like manticore says, I prefere to avoid this event when I open the page. And all the solutions I found launch it at the openning ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the scroll event for that purpose:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        //Do whatever you want to do
    }
});
```

One thing you should notice is that this way when somebody scrolls to top continuously the even will be fired although you only want it once the top is hit, for this you can define the event handler as a function and put the last scrolltop value into a function local variable.

```
$(window).scroll(handleHitTop);

function handleHitTop(event) {
    var currentScrollTopValue = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (handleHitTop.lastTop === undefined) {
        handleHitTop.lastTop = currentScrollTopValue ;

        return;
    }

    if (handleHitTop.lastTop == 0 && currentScrollTopValue == 0) {
        return;
    }

    handleHitTop.lastTop = currentScrollTopValue;

    if (handleHitTop.lastTop == 0) {
        //Call your event here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, the second version works perfectly ! But have you got an idea to prevent this event when I open the page ?

Comment: Yes, if the cached value in the event handler is undefined don't fire the event and just set the value to the currentScrollTopValue..

Comment: Code Edited to do that.. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Use the onscroll event. Vanilla js example:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
        alert('yay!');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kuWuf/

Answer (score 6):

Use a `.scroll()` handler and `.scrollTop()`:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        alert("Top!!!");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/wvJ9r/