# Is there any event to be triggered when an element is visited in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

There are four `<section>`s in my [website](http://www.aalulbaytisp.com/). There is a website navigator at the top right and it works well with keyboard top/bottom buttons and mouse click but when the user scrolls the scrollbar, the site navigator color doesn't change to green. Is there any event to findout if any of the `<section>`s is not being visited?

Comment: What do you mean by visited? .mouseover or "seen" in the user's window (.scrollTop, scrollLeft)?

Comment: You could check whether the user is reached at the top of an element within the `onscroll` event of the `window`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123081/how-can-i-launch-a-javascript-or-jquery-event-when-i-reach-the-top-of-my-page